# Automatically rename a user input code to a specific name according to menu list c++

Tags: c++

I've been struggling here on how to automatically rename a meal code when a user input a specific meal code, for example it choses s1 and after that it displays like this

```
Summary of Order
1 * 5.00 Burger
```

here's the code

```
//Meal code s1 is burger
//meal code s2 is pizza

    cout << "\tHow many meal codes?: ";
    cin >> u_code_num;
    
    for (int i=0; i<u_code_num; i++)
    {
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Meal Code: ";
        cin >> u_code[i];
        if (u_code[i] == "s1")
        {
            strcpy(meal_ordered, "Burger");
            meal_price = 5.00;
        }
        else if (u_code[i] == "s2")
        {
            strcpy(meal_ordered, "Pizza");
            meal_price = 6.00;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Meal code doesn't exist!"
        }
    }
    cout << "Customer Name: " << cust_name << endl;
    cout << "Customer Address: " << cust_add << endl;
    cout << "Customer Contact Number: " << cust_num << endl;
    cout << "Summary of Order\n";
    for (int i=0; i<u_code_num; i++)
    {
        cout << i << meal_ordered << meal_price;
        cout << "\n";
    }
```

Comment: You are not showing the declaration of most variables. This means that the type of the variables that you are using is unknown to us. This makes it impossible for us to tell whether your posted code is correct or not. Please provide a [mre], which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives.

Comment: Side note: `cin.ignore();` will only extract a single character from the input stream. This will probably be sufficient in most cases, but if there are more leftover characters on that line that were not extracted by `operator >>`, then the newline character will not be extracted. Therefore, it would probably be better to use `cin.ignore( numeric_limits<stream_size>::max, '\n' );`. See the documentation for [`std::istream::ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) for further information.

Comment: Your question would be of higher quality if you specified which parts of your program work and which parts don't, and if you elaborated on what the exact problem is. If you are not sure which parts of your program are working and which parts aren't, then you may want to read this: [How to debug small programs?](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Should `meal_ordered` be an array, shouldn't it?